# Why does decreasing font-size increases line spacing?

Tags: css

Why does a <span> of reduced font-size *increase* the line spacing?

Why does this HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Morbi in <span>odio dictum, 
cursus augue sed, </span>dictum purus. Etiam 
accumsan quam et turpis elementum, in tempor. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Morbi in odio dictum, cursus
augue sed, dictum purus. Etiam accumsan quam 
et turpis elementum, in tempor.</p>
```

and this CSS

```
p    {font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px}
span {font-size: 6px}
```

*increase* the space between the line containing the span and the following line?

How can I stop that?

(I have tried various combinations of line-height, without success.)

https://jsfiddle.net/mccaskey/xnf9pz3a/

Comment: adjust the line-height of the span also, decrease it less than the line-height of p.. I know why but I cannot explain it very well ...

Comment: Hmm. It works if I make the line-height of the span less than the font-size of the surrounding text. Why?

Comment: honestly it's a bit complicated :) I won't find the correct way to explain it as me too I don't know all the tricks behind ... simply wait and you will get an answer ;)

Comment: a hint that will probably help you is that the line-height is inherited so the span is also having 24px as line-height and the magic starts there

Comment: See the [digression at the end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282391/understanding-css2-1-specification-regarding-height-on-inline-level-boxes/52285183#52285183)

Comment: @Alohci if we can *see* it, it will be nice .. we can only *read* it :p ... It would be perfect if we can have an illustration to really see those pixel of difference.

Comment: This stuff is... complicated: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: @sol even that article doesn't say exactly why .. we can only read `As strange as it sounds, default baseline alignment may result in a higher (!) line-box` .. well, we need to read the article at least twice to probably get the calculation involved.

Comment: I once gave an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21575694/1016716), does that help? In fact, it looks like this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @MrLister yes, this is exactly the illustration missing from Alohci explanation in both answers ;)

Comment: Thanks all. And especially thanks for that illustration, @MrLister!