# Is line-height: 1.4 the same as line-height: 140%?

Tags: html, css, line-height

Is using a `line-height` value of 1.4 the same as using a `line-height` value of 140%? In other words, can we consider unitless value the same as percentage value?

Comment: Each line becomes 1.4 lines in height, so it is 140% of it's original height based on your font-size. This is not the same as `height:140%;` since width and height `%`'s are based on the parent Element. `line-height` is not based on the parent Element, so `line-height:140%;` is the same as `line-height:1.4;`.

Comment: @Hermes please don't change the question meaning! pay attention to your edits

Answer (score 8):

There are not *exactly*<sup>1</sup> the same because of inheritance, here is a trivial example.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box > span {
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box > span > span{
  font-size: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span style="line-height:1.8;"><span>some text here</span></span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span style="line-height:180%;"><span>some text here</span></span>
</div>
```

In the first case, the last span will have a value of `line-height` equal to `45px` which is `1.8 * (50% of 50px)` where `1.8` is the inherited value of line-height from its parent. In the second case, the last span will have a value equal to `90px` which is `180% of 50px` where the whole value is inherited from its parent.

In other words, the first span get the `1.8` then will consider its `font-size` while the second span will get the computed value from its parent and `font-size` will change nothing.

> `<number>`
>
> The used value of the property is this number multiplied by the element's font size. Negative values are illegal. **The computed value is the same as the specified value.**
>
> `<percentage>`
>
> **The computed value of the property is this percentage multiplied by the element's computed font size**. Negative values are illegal. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)</sup>

Note how in both cases, the computed value isn't the same which make the inheritance different in both cases.

To better illustrate the percentage case:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box > span {
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 180%;
}

.box > span > span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:50px;">some text </span></span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:50%;">some text </span></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:20px;">some text </span></span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:5px;">some text </span></span>
</div>
```

If you inspect the elements, you can clearly see how in all the cases the value of the `line-height` is equal to `90px`

Refer to this question to understand why the box height is getting bigger: [Why would the height increase with a smaller font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21570239/8620333)

If we consider unitless value we will have a different result:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box > span {
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.box > span > span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:50px;">some text </span></span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:50%;">some text </span></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:20px;">some text </span></span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span ><span style="font-size:5px;">some text </span></span>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If we omit the inheritance fact and we consider only the element where we **explicitly** set the `line-height` then we can say that both are the same since they will give the same result for the **concerned** element.

Answer (score -2):

See example..

```html
<div style="background:green;">
  <p style="line-height:1.4;">This is demo Text. <br>This is demo Text.</p>
</div>
<div  style="background:green;">
  <p style="line-height:140%;">This is demo Text. <br>This is demo Text.</p>
</div>
```