# Why does a heading have a larger height when its line-height is set and it has a span with smaller font?

Tags: html, css, font-size, line-height

Here is my code:

```css
div {
  border: thin solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  background: lightblue;
}
span {
  background: orange;
}
.b h1 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.c span {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
.d h1 {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.d span {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"><h1>Foo<span>Bar</span></h2></div>
<div class="b"><h1>Foo<span>Bar</span></h2></div>
<div class="c"><h1>Foo<span>Bar</span></h2></div>
<div class="d"><h1>Foo<span>Bar</span></h2></div>
```

There are four `div`s. Each `div` has an `h1` and a `span` nested in `h1`. Only the `line-height` and `font-size` styles are relevant for this question. The other styles are just for visualising the issue. Here is what to focus on,

1. `div.a` is a normal div. There is no styling of `line-height` or `font-size` here.
2. `div.b` only styles `h1` to have `line-height: 1.2`.
3. `div.c` only styles `span` to have `font-size: small`.
4. `div.d` styles both `h1` to have `line-height: 1.2` and `span` to have `font-size: small`.

Why does the heading in `div.d` have a larger height than the others?

Comment: the trick is that in the last example the span will inherit the line-height and the story begin there (read the duplicate for the full story)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am aware that `span` will inherit the `line-height` but that holds for `div.c` too. The default `line-height` for `h1` in the browser is `1.2` anyway, so even in `div.c`, the `span` inherits a `line-height` of `1.2` and thus becomes equivalent to `div.d`. Why doesn't `div.c` have a larger height like that of `div.d` then?

Comment: `1.2` and `1.2em` aren't the same, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60109105/8620333 (the question explain using percetange but em behave like percentage)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That was the issue! I was aware of the duplicate link but I completely overlooked that I used `1.2em` when I intended `1.2` actually. Knowing this, the issue is resolved now. Thank you for your help!