# How css inheritance works with relative units?

Tags: css, browser, frontend

I was expecting relative units to be recalculated when inherited, so that in the below example, the child element should be bigger than its parent:

```css
.parent {
  font-size: 1.5em; /* Updated font size for the parent */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Parent with updated font-size 1.5em
    <div class="child">
        Child with inherited font-size (calculated: 1.5 * 1.5em)
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the font size of the child class not calculated as intended? What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't provided a full picture here. The child will inherit the parent font size unless the child has a specified font size.

Comment: Since I haven't provided font-size of child, it should be inherited from parent, i.e. font-size of child should 1.5em which should result in the font size of child being 1.5 times larger than the parent. But the actual result shows the size of parent and child same, I don't know why

Comment: Ah so you expect inherited relative units to be calculated again at each nesting level? They're not, indeed. The computed value is inherited. https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inheritance

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

During [inheritance](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inheritance), the [computed-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#computed-value) is used, not the [specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#specified-value) one. So your relative unit has been *absolutized* before it's been applied to the child element.

> Inheritance propagates property values from parent elements to their children. The inherited value of a property on an element is the [computed value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#computed-value) of the property on the element’s parent element.

Comment: That answers my question well. Thanks!
You said "The relative unit has been absolutized before it's applied to child element". Can you shed some light on when units are absolutized during rendering?

Comment: It's done in the "recalc" phase, which may happen even before rendering, e.g. if you get some properties from JS like `element.offsetWidth`, and it will happen before paint if the styles have been dirtied, right before the ResizeObserver callbacks are fired.

Comment: @VedTimbadiya there are some exception like with line-height (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60109105/8620333) so always refer to the documentation to verify.